# Cannot output the contents of an EditText element inside onClick method

Tags: java, android

I'm relatively new at developing applications in `Android Studio` or `Java` and recently ran into a problem I just can't figure out. For now, all I'm trying to achieve is to output the content of the `EditText` field after a `Button` is been clicked.

Since I will most likely add more buttons to the `Activity` later on, I thought that it would be more handy to use a generic `onClick` where you can separate different button actions inside the `switch` statement.

Here's a working example in which the `onClickListener` which does not use a generic `onClick` method:

```
package com.example.user.myapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private EditText testText;
    private Button testButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

      // initialize UI elements
      final EditText testText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.testText);
      testButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.testButton);

      // set onClick listener 
      testButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
          // it will print the content of testText as long as the "testText" variable is declared as final
          System.out.println(testText.getText().toString().trim());
        }
      });
    }
}
```

Now, if I try to use a generic `onClick` method, I will suddenly receive a following error:

`java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference`

Here's the code that that causes the error referred above:

```
package com.example.user.myapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;


public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private EditText testText;
    private Button testButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // initialize the UI elements
        EditText testText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.testText);
        Button testButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.testButton);

        // set onClick Listener
        testButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch(v.getId()) {
            case R.id.testButton:                       
                // this will result in an error                                       
                System.out.println(testText.getText().toString().trim());
                break;
            default:
                break;
    }
}
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Share your layout?

Comment: you define `EditText testText` twice

Comment: Use either global or local variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

on your second code you have defined `testText` twice

that will work

package com.example.user.myapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private EditText testText;
    private Button testButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // initialize the UI elements
        testText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.testText);
        testButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.testButton);

        // set onClick Listener
        testButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch(v.getId()) {
            case R.id.testButton:                       
                // this will result in an error                                       
                System.out.println(testText.getText().toString().trim());
                break;
            default:
                break;
    }
}
```

Comment: As soon as it will be possible, I will accept this answer :) Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Decalre editText globally:

```
private EditText testText;
```

Get the view in onCreate():

```
testText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.testText);
```

Use it in the onClick:

```
System.out.println(testText.getText().toString().trim());
```

Answer (score 1):

You never initialize the `private EditText testText;` because you use a **local** variable instead of referencing the class field in the following call:

```
final EditText testText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.testText);
```

The `onClick(View v)` is a method of anonymous class implementing the `OnClickListener` interface and this method references the **uninitialized** field variable **testText**.

To fix this, remove the type declaration of a variable before calling `findViewById()`:

```
this.testText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.testText)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have declare EditText 2 time, one is globally and another one is inside the onCreate method, and when you are using Edittext outside the onCreate, you are getting global variable which is not initialize, thats why you are getting this error. use this,

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private EditText testText;
    private Button testButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // initialize the UI elements
        testText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.testText);
        testButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.testButton);

        // set onClick Listener
        testButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch(v.getId()) {
            case R.id.testButton:                       
                // this will result in an error                                       
                System.out.println(testText.getText().toString().trim());
                break;
            default:
                break;
    }
}
```